# ROT registration does not work with adobe 11 installed

Tags: c++, com, adobe

I have code that we've been using for years with PDFs, HTML docs, and XBRL docs.  The code is called from either a BHO in IE, or an Adobe plugin in Reader. It registers a moniker in the ROT, and creates a signalling event.

We've been trying to upgrade from Adobe 9 to Adobe 11, and the debugging the code, it simply fails to register the moniker in the ROT.  It works if called from an Adobe 9 plugin, and if called from the BHO.  But simply upgrading to Adobe 11 is enough to make it start silently failing.

The code in question is below:

```
void CLocatorRegistration::Register( ISourceLocator* pLocator, long nKeyFile )
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<IRunningObjectTable> pROT;
    CComPtr<IMoniker> pmk;
    CComBSTR bstrName;

    // access the ROT
    pROT = GetROT();

    // create the moniker
    pmk = CreateMoniker( nKeyFile );

    // put this object in the ROT. 
    _ASSERTE( !m_bRegistered );
 ->>hr = pROT->Register( ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE, pLocator, pmk, &m_dwROTCookie );
    if FAILED(hr)
        throw hr;
    m_bRegistered = true;

    // create the event and signal it, to support notification to any callers that this object
    // is now available to connect to
    CreateEventName( nKeyFile, bstrName );
    m_hEvent.Attach( ::CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, bstrName ));
    ::SetEvent( m_hEvent );
}
```

The highlighted line is the ROT registration, and the return is S_OK.  Does anyone have any idea why the method would succeed, but the entry not be placed into the ROT?

Comment: Perhaps, because of the elevated mode? For the sake of trying, temporarily turn off the UAC and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Noseratio - Good idea... but because of our own apps, UAC is already turned off.  But I do think you're on to something; I tried to access the ROT entry in the code above rather than outside, and was able to access it, even though my ROTViewer doesn't show it in the ROT, and my other application can't access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I found in researching this was the fact that Adobe 11 includes a new sandboxed protected mode setting.  When developing a plugin, it no longer by default has access to the OS.

For our purposes it was quite simple just to disable this setting, as this is for an internal application.  There are a lot of other ways to accomplish this, but we didn't look into them because of time constraints.

[image: Adobe 11 Protected Mode]